# spatie/ignition - collapse and other buttons don't work

Tags: laravel-9

I am working with Laravel 9.
In the debug page of spatie / ignition (version 1.2.3, the latest) the following operations do not work:

- the "collapse vendor frames" button
- saving the settings (top right)
- opening the editor

Update:
I add a screenshot of the error page, with the operations that cannot be performed:
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j4EB.png)

Anyone have the same problem?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.